# Combine multiple monitors into single desktop

Tags: 13.04, ati, multiple-monitors

Running Ubuntu 13.04
ATI firepro 2460

I have 2 HD monitors that I'd like to combine into a single long desktop (ie 3840px x 1080px). Not looking for 2 parallel desktops, I've already removed mirroring from system settings.

My intentions are to run a fullscreen app across 2 monitors, so I require a 'virtual' monitor spanning across the 2 screens.

Is there a standard way of implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a working solution, at least for my purposes.

After hours of search through xorg.config tutorials for multi-screen set-ups, I decided to start from scratch with AMD's stock graphics software. These are the steps I took to get fullscreen apps working across 2 screens.

1. Clean install of Ubuntu 13.04
2. Update accordingly ( `sudo apt-get update` )
3. Switch off screen mirroring in system settings
4. Download appropriate Linux x86_64 driver package from AMD, using their [search tool](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)
5. Install the package, restart, and navigate to Catalyst Control Center (Admin mode)
6. Under Display Manager > Multi-display, select Multi-display desktop.
7. Arrange/rotate screens as appropriate in screen properties.
8. Restart and navigate back to AMD CCC (admin mode).
9. Now select Overlap Compensation with automatic settings in Display Manager > Display Edges
10. Once you've restarted again, you may find a long warning notice of unavailable monitor settings ("Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors"). Just delete the monitor config file ( `sudo rm ~/.config/monitors.xml` ) and restart.

Now launching fullscreen apps (such as Chrome's Kiosk mode etc) will go fullscreen across all monitors.